# How to get length string json in js or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jqgrid

i have this code,

```
buildSelect: function (data) {
  var response = $.parseJSON(data);


  alert(response.length);
  var s = "<select>";
  if (response && response.length) {
    for (var i = 0, l = response.length; i < l; i++) {
      var ri = response[i];
      s += '<option value="' + ri.CUSTOMS_ID + '">' 
           + ri.CUSTOMS_NAME + '</option>';
    }
  }
  return s + "</select>";
}
                    },
```

i want check response  is n't null or empty and get length i write this code `response.length`
but return `undifine`
and data return

```
{"rows":[{"id":1,"cell":["1","بندرامام خميني","IMAM KHOMEINI PORT","True",null]},{"id":2,"cell":["2","آبادان","ABADAN","True",null]},{"id":3,"cell":["3","خرمشهر","KHORRAMSHAHR","True",null]},{"id":4,"cell":["4","بندرعباس","BANDAR ABBAS","True",null]},{"id":5,"cell":["5","بوشهر","BUSHEHR","True",null]},{"id":6,"cell":["6","تهران","TEHRAN","True",null]},{"id":7,"cell":["7","شيراز","SHIRAZ","True",null]},{"id":8,"cell":["8","دبي","DUBAI","True",null]}],"Page":0,"Total":0,"Records":0}
```

i want if Rows isn't empty all child add to DropDownlist

plese help me, thanks

Comment: Is data in function (data) already a JSON object?

Comment: What do you mean by 'empty'?  this '`{}`'?

Comment: if rows Isn't child example [{"id":1,"cell":["1","بندرامام خميني","IMAM KHOMEINI PORT","True",null]},....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `response` doesn't have a `length` property. However, `response.rows`, as an `Array`, does:

```
var response = $.parseJSON(data);

alert(response.rows.length);
```

You could then save a reference to `response.rows` and use that going forward:

```
var rows = response.rows;
alert(rows.length);

var s = "<select>";
if (rows && rows.length) {
  for (var i = 0, l = rows.length; i < l; i++) {
    var ri = rows[i];
    s += '<option value="' + ri.id + '">' + ri.cell[1] + '</option>';
  }
}
return s + "</select>";
```

Comment: ri.CUSTOMS_ID or ri.CUSTOMS_NAME return undifine

Comment: @mohsen Ah. That's because the names `CUSTOMS_ID` and `CUSTOMS_NAME` aren't defined within the JSON. In each iteration, `ri` will only have 2 properties -- an `id` Number and a `cell` Array. Perhaps, `ri.id` and `ri.cell[1]` are what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

`$.parseJSON(data)` returns JavaScript object and not a string. You cannot use length on an object. According to [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) `$.parseJSON` will return null if you pass in nothing, an empty string, null, or undefined.

UPD:
In your particular case it is enough to check that `response` is not `null` (no need to check the length). If data is not a valid JSON then `$.parseJSON(data)` will through an exception. You may want to catch it as well.

Comment: @JibiAbraham Check the `title` of the question.

Comment: @Engineer - check the return data the OP posted

Answer (score 1):

Once you've parsed the JSON string, in this case, you will get an **Object** in you `var response`. JavaScript objects do not have a length property. If you just want to check for a null or empty value then do one or more of the following.

```
var data = "";//in case of null data
if(!data){
    //do something
}

//or
if(data === ''){
    //do something
}
```

Now, if you want to check whether your `rows` are empty,

```
var data = {
    rows:{}
};//assuming an empty rows object

if($.isEmptyObject(data.rows)){
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since object does not contain length property/method and there is no sense for length of object.you can assign methods and properties to each object, pre-written or self-defined.

In your case try to search for object data/properties,like

> for(keys in response){
>
> check some properties related on keys
>
> }